# Backbone: how to update a property of all models with a single command

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am creating a simple list of folders which when clicked will be marked selected that is their model will have its `selected` property changed to true. I want this selection to be exclusive - all other folders should be marked unselected before a folder is marked selected.

Right all I can think of looping through the collection to change the property of every model. Is there some easier way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a project I'm working on we maintain the 'selected' item at the collection level.  We have added `getCurrent()` and `setCurrent(model)` methods and the collection will raise a `change:selection` event.  This has worked real well for us.

--EDIT: code sample per request.--

The following is part of our base.collection.js which we extend for all our collections.  You'll notice that we can set current based on id or the actual model so `col.setCurrent(123)` and `col.setCurrent(anInstanceOfAModel)` both work.  Also calling `setCurrent` for a model that is already the current doesn't fire the change event

```
    setCurrent: function (id)
    {
        var isModel = !(_.isString(id) || _.isNumber(id));

        var triggerChange = this._setupCurrent(isModel
                                ? id
                                : this.get(id));

        if (triggerChange)
            this.trigger("change:current", this._current);

        return this.getCurrent();
    },

    getCurrent: function ()
    {
        return this._current;
    },

    _setupCurrent: function (current)
    {
        var old = this._current;
        this._current = current;

        if (current && old && old.id == current.id)
            return false;

        return true;
    },
```

Comment: Does your model also have a `selected` property? The OP seems to be wondering about that.

Comment: No--mostly because I find it awkward (as it seems the OP does) to have to loop through every item in order to unset them.

Comment: @timDunham anyway you could post a code sample? I'm trying to do something very similar to what you have accomplished. Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a "state" object, in which you store the last selected folder.

Then you change that one back to not selected, without having to loop through the entire collection.